# For a graph to be cyclic, does there need to be a cycle at every node?

Tags: algorithm

Meaning if a graph has a source and a sink including other nodes, can it still be cyclic?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicGraph.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: It's not about math it's algorithms in computer science

Comment: Still off-topic for this site. Try [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's not about algorithms

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about software or software development.

Answer (score 2):

No. Example:

```
In --> B --> C --> Out
       ^     |
       |     |
       +-----+
```

Also, this is more related to [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) and they might feel insulted by your lack of Google FU.

Answer (score 2):

No. A graph is cyclic if it has at least one cycle anywhere in the graph. Any particular node may or may not be on that cycle.